# Organisation of Meteor Template that causes Uncaught RangeError?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

This may be 2 questions...

1) is there a best approach of changing pages using templates and sessions? or should logic be in the html <#if.....>

2) I have multiple forms in template b and c with capture buttons. for updating meteor.user..... I am getting this error...

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ejson.js:351
>   EJSON.cloneejson.js:351 (anonymous function)ejson.js:386
>   *.each.*.forEachunderscore.js:113 EJSON.cloneejson.js:385 (anonymous function)ejson.js:386
>   *.each.*.forEach

In client.... HTML

> template name="a" xxxxxx {{{page}}} /template
>
> template name="b" xxxxxx {{var1}} /template
>
> template name="c" xxxxxx Form.... {{var2}} /template

In client.... JS

> if session_page = "a"
>
> template.a.page = template.b({var1: test})
>
> else.....
>
> template.a.page = template.c({var2: test}) ....

many thanks. I have been pulling my hair over this issue and suspect its how i laid out my templates which causes a loop in binding reactive sub templates.... and red bull didnt help this time.

Sorry I cant post all the code.. its in a bit of a noodles situation at the moment.

Comment: For your first question, you should use a router such as [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) to handle changing pages.

Comment: hi cuberto. thanks. i am trying to make the whole page reactive as i need routing for other uses. are they any side effects doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

Quick update. Templating using the above way is fine. Performance issue isnt measured yet but it should be okay as well.

The rangeerror is caused by parsing an object rather than string.
i.e. item.value

Comment: Thanks! I had this some problem. Was trying to get value on the server side. I just re-assigned the value to the variable on the client side and passed that variable through as an argument, and the server-side worked no problem.